# Impact of move X on tendon Y

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset that contain relationships between moves and tendons, for humans. Specifically, the dataset would indicate what is the impact of move X on tendon Y.

For example (fictive), typing on a keyboard causes an effort of 10% on the lateral epicondyle of the humerus.

The effort metric would probably need to be defined, and the move may be accompanied by its duration or some other properties (e.g., keyboard type, postures, etc.).

I would be interested in any dataset that attempted to capture move vs tendon relations.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/zv7omql is considered the definitive reference here